# Given two primes $3 \leq p < q$, when $p+1$ divides $q+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $2 \leq p < q$ be two prime numbers.
Consider $p+1$ and $q+1$.

Observe that $d:=\gcd(p+1,q+1)$ can be 'anything':

(a) If $(p,q)=(2,3)$, then $(p+1,q+1)=(3,4)$, so $d=1$: $p+1,q+1$ are relatively prime.

(b) If $(p,q)=(2,5)$, then $(p+1,q+1)=(3,6)$, so $d=3=p+1$: $p+1$ divides $q+1$.

(c) If $(p,q)=(3,5)$, then $(p+1,q+1)=(4,6)$, so $d=2$: $1 < d < min\{p+1,q+1\}$.

> Is it possible to determine when case $(b)$ holds, namely, when $p+1$ divides $q+1$? (also, same question for cases $(a)$ and $(b)$).

I think that when $p=2$ the answer is not difficult (If $p=2$ and $q \geq 3$, then $p+1=3$ and $q+1$ is even, so the answer depends on whether $3$ divides $q+1$ or not; in other words, if $q \cong -1 \mod 3$ then $p+1$ divides $q+1$), so further assume that $p \neq 2$.

Comment: You've just characterized them. Assume that $p\lt q$; then case (a) can only occur if $p=2$ and $q\neq 1\pmod 3$; if $p\neq 2$ then $p+1$ and $q+1$ have 2 as a common divisor. Then case (b) is $q\equiv -1\bmod (p+1)$; and case $c$ is all the other ones.

Comment: What sort of characterization are you hoping for?  Worth noting, for any $N$, Dirichlet tells us that there are infinitely many primes congruent to $-1\pmod N$, so we can easily make $\gcd (p+1,q+1)$ as large as we want.

Comment: @lulu, did you mean "so we can easily make $\gcd(p+1,q+1)$ as large as we want including $\gcd(p+1,q+1)=p+1$"?

Comment: Sure.  Take any $p$ you like and define $N=p+1$.  Then use Dirichlet to guarantee the existence of infinitely many primes $q\equiv -1\pmod N$.  For all of these, $p+1\,|\,q+1$ by definition.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, thank you. Your comment, together with lulu's comment is the answer I was looking for (so you and/or lulu can write your comments as answers, if you like).

Comment: @lulu, I am a little confused. Perhaps I have not explained myself correctly, but I meant that $p$ and $q$ are given in advance, so it may happen that my given $q$  does not satisfy $q \cong -1 \mod N$.

Comment: Well, perhaps I am confused.  If $p$ and $q$ are known, then you know whether $p+1$ divides $q+1$ or not...so what is there to decide?

Comment: As I asked initially, what sort of characterization are you hoping for?  My argument (well, Dirichlet's argument) shows that there are infinitely many instances of case $b$ for each prime $p$. What else would you want to say?

Comment: I think I understand what you meant to say, but still, I want somehow to characterize such $q$'s, not just to know that there exist (infinitely many) such $q$'s.

Comment: (You can write your comments as an answer, if you like).

Comment: Sorry, not following,  For $p=3$ my construction comes down to showing there are infinitely many primes congruent to $3\pmod 4$.  Other than through Dirichlet, how would you characterize those?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think that what I initially meant, though I have not explained correctly, is that if $2 < p$ is given (in your example: $p=3$), then how to characterize $p < q$ such that $p+1|q+1$ ($4 | q+1$; which you have answered: $q$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$). This is what @StevenStadnicki mentioned in his comment. But I really like your comments also.

Comment: At first place I have asked for characterization of all three cases, not just case $(b)$.